# Passing parameters in body in POST API Call to Openstack Nova

Tags: rest, openstack, openstack-nova

I am trying to stop a running server instance on Openstack Nova. I am using the following API as a reference

https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#stop-server-os-stop-action

The following is my code snippet

```
import openstack.config
self.cloud_region = openstack.config.OpenStackConfig().get_one('adminproject')
self.session = self.cloud_region.get_session_client('compute')
```

I am able to make GET requests to the server

```
response = self.session.get(url)
```

But when i try to make POST requests, I am getting errors. This is how I am trying to do it

```
url = "/servers/" + vm_id + "/action
body = {"os-stop":"null"}

reponse = self.session.post(url, {'os-stop' : 'null'})

TypeError: post() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I have also tried

```
reponse = self.session.post(url, body=body)
```

which gives me an error

```
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'body'
```

When i do it via the nova client and enable the debug mode, this is what i get

```
curl -g -i -X POST http://IP:PORT/v2.1/12bf80bc27cf4fdc87a2ce2cb0619159/servers/93bc82d4-7a3b-4f67-bc6e-dfb2553a57fc/action -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}447e97116c71efcff1a02f4d7fdf8d76a4490d9d" -d '{"os-stop": null}'
```

It would be great if someone can help in finding out how to emulate the above request.

TIA.